# Automatically creating a Dear *sender's name*, in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I would like to automate the process of creating the first part of an email, namely "Dear *sender's name*" in Outlook. I believe it is possible as the name can be derived from the name field of the person who has sent the email (i.e. *name field* [ *email field* ] which appears at the top of the email) . How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you mean when a new e-mail arrives from someone you don't know, and you hit reply? You want it to extract the person's e-mail address and then add "Dear sender's name" to the reply?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Mail Merge feature and the Microsoft Outlook [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20130615181101/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2008/09/23/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx) runs through how to set that up

> The basic steps to creating a mail merged e-mail from Outlook are:
>
> 1. Select your contacts in Outlook
> 2. Select to send an e-mail in the Mail Merge dialog and choose your
>    subject
> 3. Compose your e-mail in Word – inserting fields where appropriate
> 4. Preview and Send

Read about the details on the blog article linked above.

Comment: Please don't just post a link, if you do the answer becomes worthless if the link expires.

Comment: @Nifle sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub InsertNameInReply()

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MsgReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strGreetName As String
Dim lGreetType As Long

 ' set reference to open/selected mail item
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
    Set Msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
    Set Msg = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Case Else
End Select
On Error GoTo 0

If Msg Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitProc

strGreetName = Mid$(Msg.SenderName, 2 + InStr(1, Msg.SenderName, ", ", Len(Msg.SenderName)) - 1)

Set MsgReply = Msg.Reply

With MsgReply
    .Subject = "RE:" & Msg.Subject
    .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-family : verdana;font-size : 10pt""><p>Hello " & strGreetName & ",</p></span>" & .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With

ExitProc:
Set Msg = Nothing
Set MsgReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you provided a bit of explanation. We want to teach others here how to fish for life, not just feed them for a day.

Comment: where should this pice of code be used?